# Start Websocket Project with the "normal" IIS instead of the IIS express Version

Tags: iis, express, websocket

I made a websocket web application but found out, that it won't work with the IIS express.

My question is: how can I run my websocket site with the full IIS version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the site using `Local IIS`

- Go to your projects properties (right-click the project file)
- Web -> Servers -> Local IIS

Note that IIS is not included in the default Windows 8 or Windows 7 configuration. If you have not installed IIS, do the following:

- Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off.
- Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features
- Make sure that ASP.NET 4.5 is selected

Comment: Thx. Do you know how i get the permissions to connect to the local IIS? because when I try to save the properties a popup tells me that I dont have permissions to connet to the IIS Metabase... :/ @sjokkogutten

Comment: Try running as administrator. (right click as select 'run as administrator')